# Liferay Autofield with DatePicker

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui, liferay-ide, liferay-aui, autofield

I have a aui form with Liferay.Autofields enabled.

The fields that I am duplicating with Autofield has a button and a textfield. The button click will trigger the datepicker and the selected value should be stored in the textfield.
And, when I click the "PLUS" button provided by Autofield, the fields are duplicated.

First, I need to know how I can bind the trigger event of all buttons to the datepicker. I know to do this for a single button. But since we are using autofield, I need to give the ID of the button with the index. Can anyone suggest how to bind the trigger event in my scenario

Second, once I click the date picker button, I should be able to get index of the Autofield row in which I have clicked, so that I can update my textfield